# Combine 2 Conditions of AWK in 1 set of forward slashs

Tags: awk

I have a file where I need only 18th column and that 18th column must not contain 30 words like

AAA, BBB, CCC etc

```
Sample file 

$ cat a.csv 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,Aaa
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,BBB



awk -F, '!($18 ~ /AAA/) && !($18 ~ /BBB/) {print $18 }'
```

It's possible to write something like

```
awk -F, '!($18 ~ /AAA, BBB /) {print $18 }'
```

**EDIT**

If I use

```
i=$("AAA|BBB")
awk -F, '!($18 ~ /$i/) {print $18 }'
```

it produces error `command not found`

Comment: Please, post a proper sample with the expected output for testing, a few records of data with both positive and negative matches. Also, it doesn't have to be 18 fields, post for example 2 fields and then `$2` -> `$18`.

Comment: @JamesBrown the actual question is 

"How to Combine 2 Conditions of AWK in 1 set of forward slashs"

Comment: @ProCoder: is this really such a bad question? I've seen questions here on this site, which are far worse than this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the alternation operator `|` and use something like

```
awk -F',' '$18 !~ /AAA|BBB|CCC/{print $18}' a.csv
```

Comment: If I use 

    i=$("AAA|BBB")
    awk -F, '!($18 ~ /$i/) {print $18 }'

it produces error `command not found`
I update in question too

Comment: Don't use a command substitution which tries to execute your string.  You can use a string as regexp and pass the variable to `awk` using `-v` like `i='AAA|BBB|CCC'; awk -v i="$i" -F',' '$18 !~ i{print $18}' a.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply strip lines where a field is one of a set of blacklist entries, you can create the blacklist *once* in the `BEGIN` section, then simply use `~` to see if that blacklist contains your field.

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to construct the blacklist using the input field separator (so you *know* it won't be part of the field). With an `input.csv` file of:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,AAA
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,BBB
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,CCC
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,DDD
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,EEE
```

Let's say you don't want lines where field 18 is `AAA`, `BBB` or `DDD`:

```
pax> awk -F, 'BEGIN{ss=",AAA,BBB,DDD,"}ss!~","$18","{print}' input.csv
CCC
EEE
```

Below, we'll break down how it works:

```
BEGIN {
    ss=",AAA,BBB,DDD,"   # This is the blacklist, note IFS separator and start/end.
}
ss !~ ","$18"," {         # If ",<column 18>," not in blacklist, print.
    print $18
}
```

The trick is to create a string which is the column we're checking surrounded by the delimiters (which cannot be *in* the column). If we find that in the blacklist (which is every unwanted item surrounded by the delimiter), we can discard it.

---

Note that you're not restricted to a *fixed* blacklist (either in your string or if you decide to use a regex solution), you can if you wish read the entries from a file and dynamically construct the list. For example, consider the file `blacklist.txt`:

```
AAA
BBB
DDD
```

and the `input.txt` file as shown above. The following `awk` command can dynamically create the blacklist from that file thusly:

```
pax> awk -F, 'BEGIN{ss=","}NR==FNR{ss=ss""$1",";next}ss!~","$18","{print}' blacklist.txt input.csv
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,CCC
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,EEE
```

Again, breaking it down:

```
BEGIN {
    ss = ","           # Start blacklist.
}
NR==FNR {              # Only true for first file in list (blacklist).
    ss = ss""$1","     # Extend blacklist.
    next               # Go get next line.
}
ss !~ ","$18"," {      # Only get here for second file (input).
    print
}
```

Here, we process the first file to construct the blacklist (rather than having a fixed one). Lines in the second file are treated as per my original script above.